# Showing that the algebra of $\mu *$ measurable sets is equal to another algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let's say I define the algebra, containing all sets that are $\mu *$ measurable as : $$\mathcal A(\mu^*) := \{A \subseteq X |  \mu^*(Q) = \mu ^*(Q\cap A) + \mu ^*(Q \cap A^c) :\forall Q \subseteq X\}$$
whereas $\mu ^*$ is an outer measure on a semiring $\mathcal H$. Now I want to show that for the set $$M(\mu ^*) := \{A \subseteq X |  \mu^*(Q) = \mu ^*(Q\cap A) + \mu ^*(Q \cap A^c) :\forall Q \in \sigma(\mathcal H)\}$$the equality $A(\mu^*) = M(\mu^*)$ holds. It is clear to me that $M(\mu^*) \supseteq A(\mu^*)$ generally holds, so I would only have to show the other direction. However, I am not sure where to start.